# Snakemake: HISAT2 alignment of many RNAseq reads against many genomes UPDATED

Tags: snakemake

I have several genome files with suffix .1.ht2l to .8.ht2l

```
bob.1.ht2l
...
bob.8.ht2l
steve.1.ht2l 
...
steve.8.ht2l
```

and sereval RNAseq samples

```
flower_kevin_1.fastq.gz
flower_kevin_2.fastq.gz
flower_daniel_1.fastq.gz
flower_daniel_2.fastq.gz
```

I need to align all rnaseq reads against each genome.
UPDATED as dariober suggested:

```
workdir: "/path/to/aligned"  
(HISAT2_INDEX_PREFIX,)=glob_wildcards("/path/to/index/{prefix}.1.ht2l")
(SAMPLES,)=glob_wildcards("/path/to/{sample}_1.fastq.gz") 
print(HISAT2_INDEX_PREFIX)  
print (SAMPLES)

rule all:
    input: 
        expand("{prefix}.{sample}.bam", zip, prefix=HISAT2_INDEX_PREFIX, sample=SAMPLES)

rule hisat2:
    input:
        hisat2_index=expand("%s.{ix}.ht2l" % "/path/to/index/{prefix}", ix=range(1, 9), prefix = HISAT2_INDEX_PREFIX),
        fastq1="/path/to/{sample}_1.fastq.gz",
        fastq2="/path/to/{sample}_2.fastq.gz"
    output:
        bam = "{prefix}.{sample}.bam",
        txt = "{prefix}.{sample}.txt",
    log: "{prefix}.{sample}.snakemake_log.txt"
    threads: 5
    shell:
      "/Tools/hisat2-2.1.0/hisat2 -p {threads} -x {/path/to/index/{wildcards.prefix}"
      " -1 {input.fastq1} -2 {input.fastq2}  --summary-file {output.txt} |"
      "/Tools/samtools-1.9/samtools sort -@ {threads} -o {output.bam}"
```

The problem I get is when running HISAT2 is taking as -x input all bob.1.ht2l:bob.8.ht2l and steve.1.ht2l:steve.8.ht2l at once. While rna-seq should be mapped at each genome separately. Where is the error?
NB: my previous question: [Snakemake: HISAT2 alignment of many RNAseq reads against many genomes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59460188/snakemake-hisat2-alignment-of-many-rnaseq-reads-against-many-genomes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your confusion comes from the fact that hisat wants a *prefix* to the index files, not all the list of index files. So instead of `-x {input.hisat2_index}` (i.e. the list of index files) use something like `-x /path/to/{wildcards.prefix}`.

In other words, the input `hisat2_index=expand(...)` should be there only to tell snakemake to start this rule only after these files are ready but you don't use them directly (well, hisat does use them of course but you don't pass them on the command line).

Comment: Hi dariober, thanks a lot for a suggestion, I still get all genomes in the input, is it normal, would it work anyway? something like this: `rule hisat2:
    input: bob.1.ht2l...bob.8.ht2l, steve.1.ht2l...steve.8.ht2l
    output: bob.flower_kevin.bam, bob.flower_kevin.txt
    log: bob.flower_kevin.snakemake_log.txt
    jobid: 2
    wildcards: prefix=bob, sample=flower_kevin`

Comment: @user3224522 can you update your post to show the code you have tried? It's difficult to tell what's wrong otherwise

Comment: sure, I updated, I added `-x {/path/to/index/{wildcards.prefix}` as you suggested

Comment: You have an extra `{`. Instead of `-x {/path/...` you should have `-x /path/to/index/{wildcards.prefix}`. Apart from that, it may be good. Just try to run it and see. Run snakemake with `-p` (to print shell commands) and `-n` (for dry run)

Comment: yes, sorry, there is no extra `{` (typing error), I run it as you wrote above..anyway when I run I can see the list of all genomes in input section, but we have wildcards it should run for all separately right?